# How to load the pre-trained doc2vec model and use it's vectors

Tags: python, numpy, gensim, doc2vec

Does anyone know which function should I use if I want to use the pre-trained doc2vec models in this website https://github.com/jhlau/doc2vec?

I know we can use the `Keyvectors.load_word2vec_format()`to laod the word vectors from pre-trained word2vec models, but do we have a similar function to load pre-trained doc2vec models as well in gensim?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

When a model like `Doc2Vec` is saved with gensim's native `save()`, it can be reloaded with the native `load()` method:

```
model = Doc2Vec.load(filename)
```

Note that large internal arrays may have been saved alongside the main filename, in other filenames with extra extensions – and all those files must be kept together to re-load a fully-functional model. (You still need to specify only the main save file, and the auxiliary files will be discovered at expected names alongside it in the same directory.)

You may have other issues trying to use those pre-trained models. In particular:

- as noted in the linked page, the author used a custom variant of gensim that forked off about 2 years ago; the files might not load in standard gensim, or later gensims
- it's not completely clear what parameters were used to train those models (though I suppose if you succeed in loading them you could see them as properties in the model), and how much meta-optimization was used for which purposes, and whether those purposes will match your own project
- if the parameters are as shown in one of the repo files, `[train_model.py][1]`, some are inconsistent with best practices (a `min_count=1` is usually bad for `Doc2Vec`) or apparent model-size (a mere 1.4GB model couldn't hold 300-dimensional vectors for all of the millions of documents or word-tokens in 2015 Wikipedia)

I would highly recommend training your own model, on a corpus you understand, with recent code, and using metaparameters optimized for your own purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answers gogomo! but unfortunately I couldn't load the model using the load() method, and that's why I search for help in stackflow to find if there is anyone who write some code to fix that problem (and the gensim version problem as well).

Comment: You don't mention what error or block you hit that means you "couldn't load" it, so it's hard to be sure what the problem might be. But as the model's author mentions, you probably need to use his old custom fork of gensim as available on Github. Did you try that? If not, that's the 1st thing to try. But also: even if that succeeds, you may be disappointed with that model, for all the reasons I've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import gensim.models as g

model="model_folder/doc2vec.bin"  #point to downloaded pre-trained doc2vec model

#load model
m = g.Doc2Vec.load(model)
```